# What is the MySQL KEY value (in desc table) for a multicolumn primary key?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table:

```
create table t (
        n1 int, n2 int, index (n1, n2),
        u1 int, u2 int, unique index (u1, u2));
```

According to the [SHOW COLUMNS documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html) I was expecting `Key = UNI` for `u1` because of

> If Key is UNI, the column is the first column of a UNIQUE index. (A UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values, but you can tell whether the column permits NULL by checking the Null field.)

What am I missing?

.

**Output of `desc t;` (without the columns `Default` and `Extra`)**

```
Field   Type    Null    Key     Default Extra
n1      int(11) YES     MUL
n2      int(11) YES
u1      int(11) YES     MUL
u2      int(11) YES
```

.

**Output of `show index from t;` (without some irrelevant columns)**

```
Table   Non_unique      Key_name Seq_in_index   Column_name     Cardinality
t   0           u1  1           u1          0
t   0           u1  2           u2          0
t   1           n1  1           n1          0
t   1           n1  2           n2          0
```

Comment: I think your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317889/sql-keys-mul-vs-pri

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to account for question update:**

If multiple columns are involved in a unique index, the individual columns might show MUL rather than UNI because even though the two columns together must always be unique, the individual columns might not be.

From your link:

> UNIQUE index may display as MUL if several columns form a composite UNIQUE index; although the combination of the columns is unique, each column can still hold multiple occurrences of a given value.

Comment: Ouch, I meant UNI, I have quoted the relevant part. I am sorry for changing my mind again.

Comment: @Matt Davies - please can you edit your post to show the extract as a blockquote, rather than as code? Prefix the line with `>` rather than four spaces. I can't change this as the edit is deemed "too trivial". Thanks!

Comment: Have updated based on your new question :) Noted @nurdglaw, thanks!