# Mysql drop primary key doesn't work

Tags: mysql

Here is my table:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| template_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type        | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | 2       |                |
| width       | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |                |
| height      | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can tell from the table, the `id` and `template_id` are the primary key, and the `id` has an auto_increment setting.

What I want to do is drop the `tempalte_id` primary key attribute.

Here is the mysql query string I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE ts_template_size
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

The query could execute successfully, but seems nothing changed. No warning, no error, and the `tempalte_id`'s primary key attribute still there

So how can I fix this? What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL keys, MUL vs PRI vs UNI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317889/sql-keys-mul-vs-pri-vs-uni)

Comment: What makes you think that `template_id` is a primary key? I can't tell it from the table structure you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

Alter for autoincrement

```
ALTER TABLE ts_template_size MODIFY id INT NULL;
```

Drop

```
ALTER TABLE ts_template_size
DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

And recreate it:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: Directly drop primary key could cause an error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Try altering for remove the autoincrement first

Answer (score 1):

"What's wrong with my query?"

Your query *is* dropping the primary key `id` in your table and then immediately re-adding it. There is no error message because the query works.

The problem is that `template_id` is not a primary key in your table. This should work:

```
ALTER TABLE ts_template_size drop index `template_id`;
```

Your `id` primary key will remain, as you desire.

See this answer for more on the `MUL` index designation (which is what `template_id` is in your table):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15268888/1250190

Comment: @hh54188 The create table query you show in http://stackoverflow.com/q/40297345/1250190 verifies that `template_id` is not a primary key in the `ts_template_size` table.