# Mysql insert operation cause table be locked

Tags: mysql

Here is my create table query string and table desc:

```
CREATE TABLE `ts_template_size` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `template_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `width` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  `height` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_template_id` (`template_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134428 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| template_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type        | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | 2       |                |
| width       | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |                |
| height      | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is the insert query:

```
INSERT INTO nova_ts_liguangyi.ts_template_size  
    (id, template_id, type, width, height)  
VALUES 
    (NULL, 20002, 2, '960', '90'),
    (NULL, 20002, 2, '960', '60'),
    (NULL, 20000, 2, '960', '90'),
    (NULL, 20000, 2, '960', '60')
```

If I execute the insert individually, it could success.

However, the insert operation is execute under a transaction process, before the insert operation, there is a delete operation on the table.

This is the error I got:

```
{ [Error: ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction]
  code: 'ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT',
  errno: 1205,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  index: 0 }
```

It seems the table have been locked? Then I check the the `INNODB_LOCK` and `INNODN_TRX` table in HeidiSQL client, here is the result I got:

[image]
[image]

It seems is the insert operation case the lock? How can I fix this problem?

BTW, I operate mysql through node js module `mysqljs`, so I can't execute query with some parameters, like`--lock-table=false`

Comment: how many rows you are trying to insert in that table?

Comment: @NewbeeDev , the rows to be inserts is not a certain number, it depends on the request