# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.sports' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

[image: table: records]

It is throwing error:

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'test.sports' (errno: 150).

I need help in resolving it.

```
 CREATE TABLE sports(
-> interest text,
-> prize_money int,
-> sp_id int NOT NULL,
-> CONSTRAINT fk_sports 
-> FOREIGN KEY(sp_id)
-> REFERENCES records(id)
-> ON DELETE CASCADE
-> ON UPDATE CASCADE
-> ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: Just another bot..

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `records` table?

Comment: +------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| student_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| subject    | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| marks      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| teacher    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sex        | tinytext    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:Its not understandable...can a image be uploaded in the comment section??

Comment: The `records` table has no `id`column.  Try using `REFERENCES records(student_id)` instead.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:thanks man..thanks for the help.it worked

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: One more thing. after the creation of the sports table, the   id column is showing MUL as the key. what that means

Comment: There is no `id` column in either table.  What is `MUL` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: sorry sp_id column in the sports table.

Comment: +-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| interest    | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| prize_money | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sp_id       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |

Comment: `"MUL means that the key allows multiple rows to have the same value"` .. check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317889/sql-keys-mul-vs-pri-vs-uni

Comment: added image inline, formatted error

Answer (score 0):

Your `records` table does not have a column called `id`.  Rather, its primary key column is `student_id`, so you probably intended to reference this from the foreign key in `sports`.  Try this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE sports(
    interest text,
    prize_money int,
    sp_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_sports 
    FOREIGN KEY(sp_id)
    REFERENCES records(student_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```