# What determines if MUL is written for SQL column

Tags: mysql

If I run `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name` I get:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| convo_id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client_convo_id | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Looking at the `Key`-column, it is clear what `PRI` means, namely, primary key. `MUL`, according to my research, stands for multiple, which means there can me multiple instances of the same `user_id` in this table. But what about the `client_convo_id` field? It has no value in the `Key`-column. What does this mean? I suspect that there can be multiple entries in the table with the same `client_convo_id`. Why, then, does `client_convo_id` not have `MUL` in its `Key`-column?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` to provide more information

Answer (score 3):

MUL means that the field is part of a non-unique index, as answered here:
[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317889/sql-keys-mul-vs-pri-vs-uni)

There is nothing in the Key column for client_convo_id, because that field does not have an index attached to it.

Not all columns in SQL have indexes. Only one that are used for selection (in where or join clauses) are usually indexed, so the queries run faster. Here is the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) on the matter.