# Unset MUL KEY mysql

Tags: mysql

I have an columns with `MUL` in the `KEY`, i need unset that.

How unset `KEY MUL` in mysql command line?

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| uf_imob         | varchar(51)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to find out what's going on internally.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317889/sql-keys-mul-vs-pri-vs-uni for what `MUL` means, then it should be obvious what to do about it.

Comment: @Barmar im new in mysql, i know now what `MUL` means but i still 
without knowing how unset that, u have any tip?

Comment: Use `ALTER TABLE` to change the indexes.

Comment: Why do you want to unset it?